# Scroll to Content | Kendo UI Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-mobile

I have tried here **[myjsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshpattu/28Auc/1/)** 
I am trying to show login section when user clicks any link on the home page. I will show the home page again when user clicks on logo which is there in the header.
The problem is if the scroll down on the home page and click any link then the in the login section also scroll downed I want to scroll to the top of the login section How to do that here.
Script is here :

```
var kendoMobileApplication = 
    new kendo.mobile.Application($(document.body),{ skin: 'flat' });



$('.homePage-nav-menu-list >li>a').click(function(){
    $('.homePage-nav-menu-list').hide();
    $('.loginSec').show();
});

$('.logoImg').click(function(){
    $('.homePage-nav-menu-list').show();
    $('.loginSec').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`reset()`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/mobile/scroller#methods-reset) method on `scroller()`.

```
var app = new kendo.mobile.Application();
app.scroller().reset();
```

Reference: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/mobile/application#methods-scroller

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/LeaKv/)**